# vue js app image not loading from server

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

In my Vue js app, 
image is loading on my localhost environment form "src/assets" folder  but when i deploy it on firebase images are not showing .404 is showing . what the problem here?

```html
i am using: 
<img src="../assets/logo.png" style="width:100%" alt="Avatar">:
i also tried:
 "<img :src="../assets/logo.png" style="width:100%" alt="Avatar">"
```

Comment: Are you using some module bundler like webpack?

Comment: yes i am using webpack

Comment: Take a look to this folder structure https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/0p200P3Q3L0W390S2441/Image%202018-05-08%20at%2012.49.05%20PM.png?v=d6d5811e, then if you are calling your image from app.vue you should call load it like this: `<img src="./assets/logo.png" style="width:100%" alt="Avatar">` and that should work.

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: YES i fix it by using the full path  "src/assets/logo.png"

Comment: Fantastic! Glad you make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give the full path instead of `../assets/logo.png` try `src/assets/logo.png` or what ever It should be complete full path.

Comment: I don't think this is a webpack issue. Give exact same path to the alt attribute and see what it gives. (<img src="src/assets/logo.png" style="width:100%" alt="src/assets/logo.png">). I think you have a path issue. If alt prints it correct and logo.png exists in that path image should appear in the screen.

Comment: src/assets/logo.png didn't work for me. But @/assets/logo.png did!